# Smali: methods to return true using sget-object

Tags: methods, reverse-engineering, smali

I've tried to implement the suggested line that I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64336006/smali-modify-methods-to-return-true), but it didn't work and the app crashed.

This is the original code:

```
.method public final getHasDrawn()Ljava/lang/String;
  .registers 2

    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/abcjean/skull/User;->hasdrawn:Ljava/lang/String;

    return-object v0

.end method
```

And by adding the new line using `sget-object`, I wrote it this way:

```
.method public final getHasDrawn()Ljava/lang/String;

    .registers 2

    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/abcjean/skull/User;->hasdrawn:Ljava/lang/String;

    sget-object v0, Lcom/abcjean/skull/User;->TRUE:Ljava/lang/String;

    return-object v0

.end method`
```

I wish I could make this method to return true, but the only problem is the app keeps crashing. So I assume that the code above is written incorrectly. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The app keeps crashing because your new code is invalid, I have added some comments to the original code:

```
.method public final getHasDrawn()Ljava/lang/String; // return type is a java.lang.String object
  .registers 2

    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/abcjean/skull/User;->hasdrawn:Ljava/lang/String; // com.abcjean.skull.User->hasdrawn is a java.lang.String object, which is read into v0

    return-object v0 // the string above

.end method
```

So there are 2 errors for your code:

1. `getHasDrawn()` is not returning a `java.lang.String`, which the other code are most likely expecting it to be doing so.
2. `com/abcjean/skull/User;->TRUE:Ljava/lang/String;` is not valid.  It should be `java/lang/Boolean;->TRUE:Ljava/lang/String;` as in the question you had linked to, if you intended to return `java.lang.Boolean.TRUE`.  The line is referring to a object identifer named `TRUE`, which is of type `java.lang.Boolean`

   - see [java.lang.Boolean's source code
     (jdk7)](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/Boolean.java)
     or the
     [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html)

I would need more context on what you are trying to achieve to truly solve your problem.

Here is a rough sketch of what a solution might be, assuming your goal is to make `getHasDrawn()` return a string primitive `"yes"`:

```
.method public final getHasDrawn()Ljava/lang/String;
  .registers 3

    iget-object v0, p0, Lcom/abcjean/skull/User;->hasdrawn:Ljava/lang/String;

    const-string v1, "yes"
    return-object v1

.end method
```

Most likely, you should be looking at other methods that returns a boolean that blocks your access to a certain view of the target app.  Unless the app uses string instead of boolean to do so.

Read more on `smali` syntax on the official docs:

- [Android OSP docs :: dalvik-bytecode](https://source.android.com/docs/core/runtime/dalvik-bytecode) (what instructions there are)
- [Android OSP docs :: dex-format#typedescriptor](https://source.android.com/docs/core/runtime/dex-format#typedescriptor) (how to define types)

---

Another suggestion unrelated to your question, is that from my experience you will have a better chance just hooking up a reverse proxy and read the API calls to achieve your reverse-engineering goals without editing the `smali` / decompiled `java` code.

Comment: I had kept the `iget-object` call in my suggested code as I am not sure what implication that will have, most likely you can just remove that line, in which case change `v1` to `v0` and change `.registers` to 1